# How do I change my blog title font size and serif typeface in views?

Tags: views

I have tried to changed the title formatting with CSS, without success. I may have done something incorrectly. I also downloaded an module that has the ability to format titles in views, but that also failed.

You can see the list of titles I would like to change here: http://www.thepoliticus.com/

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a Q+A site, and as such we need the full description of the problem you're having, what solutions you've already tried, what didn't work etc, all in the body of the question itself. Augmenting the post with a link is fine, if it will help, but the body of the question is the most important thing. Once you've clarified the problem, please click the flag link and we'll see about getting it re-opened. Thanks

Comment: Now it seems clear it's a generic CSS question that's not really on-topic here. I don't know, maybe it will be on topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Whatever you decide is fine with me. Sorry my question wasn't as clear as it could have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add a class name to the view to make it easier to specify the view
at admin/structure/views/view/[view-name]/edit -click-to- advanced click-to- CSS and create a name for the view, this will help to label the CSS.

Then:

1. If your theme has the option to change the font size and typeface, just change it in the theme. Adaptive theme can do this, https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme , for instance. If you only want one view to be different, this will not work.
2. Otherwise create a new subtheme and modify CSS as needed to change your view font-face and size. https://drupal.org/node/225125
3. An easier option: using the Sweaver module to interactively change CSS often without having to resort to editing any files, uses a GUI. https://drupal.org/project/sweaver . Be careful to only select that view.
4. Another easy option can use the CSS Injector, to create specific CSS to override existing CSS: https://drupal.org/project/css_injector and again, select the specific view element for title.